# Does a constant use a register in an FPGA?

Tags: resources, vhdl, constants

I would like to know how a constant is implemented on an FPGA.

If I declare :

```
constant my_constant : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := "11010";
```

in a VHDL code, does the place & route implement 5 DFFs ?

Thanks,

SLP

Comment: You could always try this in a simple design and look at the post-synthesis schematic

Comment: I have always seen it gets optimized away.

Comment: If one were to look in IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis (withdrawn) you'd see sequential logic was inferred by assignment on a clock edge event (for a register) or through incompletely covered conditional assignment (for a latch). A constant cannot be the target of an assignment statement guaranteeing that other than as a selectable array of element values (a selector, a look up table, a ROM) in an expression used in an assignment no logic can be inferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A constant will not use any flip flops. On it's own, it will do nothing and effectively be ignored by the synthesis engine.

If you use it in an comparison for example where you are comparing an input from some source against the constant value, then that will use some LUTs to implement that logic function (the comparison).

If you do that comparison in a synchronous (clocked) process then the output of that comparison will use some registers (flip-flops) to store the result.

As suggested already, try synthesising some simple examples and see what the tool does.

Answer (score 1):

No. A constant will not result in a flip-flop when you sythesise it.